# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'undefined' for column 'status'

Tags: laravel

Laravel Multiple Data Insert Error

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer
>   value: 'undefined' for column 'status' at row 1 (SQL: insert into
>   `schools` (`user_id`, `province_id`, `city_id`, `center_id`,
>   `national_number_founder`, `school_name`, `status`, `gender`, `note`,
>   `type`, `area`, `file_number`, `phone`, `address`, `postal_code`,
>   `building`, `date_establishment`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (1, 1, 2, 1, a, a, undefined, , , a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, 2018-07-30
>   16:00:47, 2018-07-30 16:00:47))

blade.php

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="1" value="1">Active
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="0" value="0">Deactive
</label>
```

Migration

```
$table->boolean('status');
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually runs the query?  Seems pretty straight forward, you're binding 'undefined' to the status column so debug and check the value of status when you're generating this insert.

Comment: Yes, But what should I do?

Comment: I just told you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your application is not casting "1" to 1 when saving to the database, try adding a setStatusAttribute function to your model:

```
public function setStatusAttribute($status)
{
    $this->attributes["status"] = (int)$status;
}
```

For getting the value from the database you could also use the $casts array, check [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) for more info.